# Excel VBA runs significantly slower after saving the page as a pdf

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very strange problem in my excel vba program. I have a ton of vba code that executes queries and formats data. Everything works reasonably quickly. However if I save the page as a pdf and then go back to clicking around and executing more queries. Everything takes significantly longer to run. I have to wait for up to 10 seconds for my queries to execute and show me the data. Before saving as pdf this only took a second. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks!

---

I am using excel 2007. I am creating the pdf via VBA but I have also tested by using the save as pdf button in excel and exactly the same thing happens. It only appears to slow down if I save my entire worksheet as pdf. If I select 1 graph and save it as a pdf it does not slow down. the worksheet I am trying to save consists of several comboboxes, buttons, 2 graphs and table

Comment: Some more info would be helpful; what version of Excel, and how is pdf created (via vba?)

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/1228) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7115390/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: don't save as pdf. Ever.

If you want to provide reports in pdf format, 'print' your workbook (or predefined print ranges) to the virtual printer provided by Adobe, which generates usable pdf files.

Keep the workbook as xls, and treat pdf as a presentation format with limited functionality.